# How to create object tree from xsd in Java?

Tags: java, tree, xsd

I want to know how can we create an Object tree in java from an XSD file. Is there any framework for this?

The function signature will somewhat be close to this:

```
TreeSet<Object> convertToTree(File xsdFile);
```

So you can see the function `convertToTree` should read the xsd file and generate a Tree collection.

Can someone please post some examples as well?

Answer (score 5):

You have the options of using [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) or [XMLBean](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/).

If you need an example see [generate JAXB classes from an XML schema file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxbschema2java.html) or

Do it like this: `"%java_home%\bin\xjc" -p [package_name] [xsd_file].xsd`

Comment: +1 for JAXB.  Here is a side by side comparison of using object models generated from JAXB and XMLBeans:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xmlbeans.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use JAXB for this issue.
It is even integrated in Netbeans as far as I know.

In Netbeans:

Select your project -> right click -> new

choose Other -> Category=XML; FileTypes=JAXB Binding

The rest should be self explaining.

However if you don't have a fixed xml-scheme defined by a xsd, but you want to display the structure of a xml-scheme defined by a xsd-file, you could do the following:

since a xsd-file is always a xml-file, too, you should write a xsd-file describing your xsd-files. (I'm sure there's already a scheme for xsd-file). Then you can use this xsd-file as described above to marshal and unmarshal your other xsd-files. But I didn't test this solution...

Comment: +1 - JAXB is also integrated into Eclipse.  Just right-click your XML schema and then:  Generate | JAXB Classes...

Comment: Actually the problem is not to create one time object. I need to generate a Tree<E> of Java objects from various xsds as inputs

Comment: This doesn't create one time objects. It creates a set of classes representing your xml-structure defined in xsd. Using JAXB.marshal and JAXB.unmarshal you may then create objects by parsing xml-files and create xml-Files using objects. Or what is your base intent? Maybe I misunderstood this.

Answer (score 2):

There is 'xjc' utility which comes with JDK which you could run from command line, passing your schema as a parameter. It woul generate you Java classes representing the schema structure. Then you could use these classes to convert XML to Java representation and back (see JAXB and marshalling/Unmarshalling).

Answer (score 0):

in XML Schema Definition(xsd) having some elememnt types as  and  these are the root elements while creating the object tree in xsd file.

As Kuldeep said this xsd file works with JAXB(Java Architecture for XML Binding) and JavaBean classes. This will generate the bean classes with setter and getter methods to retreive the data from bean object.

For example the Example.xsd file have the structure as mentioned below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.project.com/folder/Example" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:vsi="http://www.project.com/folder/Example" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" jxb:version="1.0">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jxb:schemaBindings>
                <jxb:package name="com.folder.jaxb.beans.example" />
            </jxb:schemaBindings>
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
```

Then define the elements with the propertys and its attributes.

Then create a build.xml file which is having script to run ant then it generates a new bean classes with the xsd object tree.

After that you can able to run the project with the xml elements.