# Is it possible to send an object to a file in a format that is human readable?

Tags: java, file-io, serializable

I am working on a project for my advanced Java class, and the assignment says he wants us
to send an object to a file, which is easy enough, but that he also wants the file to be human readable and editable. I sent him an e-mail 3 days ago and he hasn't responded, so 
I am kind of stuck between a rock and hard place since the project is due in 3 days.

So would any of you clever programmers be able to fill me in on the secret that apparently I am left out of.

How do you send an object to a file that reads like English?

> I want to have the ability to both read and write a to-do item to a
>   file. I see our application looking like:
>
> 1. When it first starts, the program asks the user if there is a file containing to-do items. If so, the user will name the file, the
>      program will read it in and continue.
> 2. When the user decides to exit, the program will prompt the user - to ask if the to-do     items should be saved to a file - if so, the
>      user will name the file and the program will     write them out in
>      such a fashion that it can read them in again.
>
> I want these file to be human readable (and editable). No binary data.
>   No counting. My advice to you would be to have a method somewhere that
>   looked like:
>
> ```
> public ToDoItem getToDoItem(FileInputStream fis) {
>    // ...
> }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> public void writeToDoItem(FileOutputStream fos) {
>  // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://java.sys-con.com/node/37550

Comment: Maybe, you can treat the aforementioned object that contains data with properties (in 1:1 relationship) that you can load from/save into like a CSV or an XML file that you can read and edit. The object is just a representation of this data. I hope you get what I mean here :)

Comment: Well putting it into an xml file would be all well and good, but the project specifically says to a text file, we might be using xml's later on when we integrate it through mysql

Comment: XML is a just a text file in a structured format :)

Comment: Thats true but the problem is I'd have to read the same object back in to the program later on

Comment: If the professor really means the object as similar as to its Java object form in the code which is serialized into its file form, then I don't think it is really English-like readable. But, if he means an object that represents a given conceptual structure materialized into a "English-like form" that readable/saveable in a file form, then you are free to implement such object easily like most libraries i.e. JAXB, etc.

Comment: Please put your quote into your original post for others to see immediately rather than to let others browse the comment section...

Comment: For the new info, it is clear to me that you a free to design an English-like Todo list text file and create a Todo class that reads an existing Todo data and saves a new Todo data in the similar text structure as to what you have formatted in your todo list text file.

Comment: This project has been a headache and a half, but I actually really understand what you're saying, I guess I would just have to design a new constructor that takes in the values being read from the file

Comment: If you still don't get the idea, look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805373/how-to-print-object-list-to-file-with-formatting-in-table-format-using-java

Comment: Yeah i think i got it now, problem was that when he said get a ToDoItem, I assumed he meant import an actual object, but its always good to get a fresh opinion, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think how you would represent an object on paper in such a way that it could be reconstructed unambiguously. You'd probably list the class name, then you'd list each field name and its current value. If the field was a primitive, the value would be just the primitive value. If it was a reference type, you'd represent the object recursively using this procedure. If it was an array, you'd list each element value.

There are various standard ways of formatting such a representation (XML and JSON to name a couple). The key is to make it a text-only representation so it is human-readable.

Comment: Well yeah I could definitely put it into the text file with the instances in that manner, but then how could i read it in as a single object?

Comment: That did it, light bulb is back on, this actually helped alot, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Think of your serialization model.  The ObjectOutputStream might write bytes, but is there another way you could represent the object and write it through some other output stream that writes human-readable text?

Comment: I know that when you serialize an object you're serializing its instances, and that you can use a printStream to print out the instances of the object, but how could you then read it back in as an object later on?

Comment: ever heard of JSON?  It's an object notation in Javascript format and would be considered human readable.  What about JAXB?  It's an object notation in xml.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend on the type of object you have. You will have to tailor it to a particular type of data.

For example, if you have an Object

```
String title;
List<Integer> ids;
```

then you could save it as JSON

```
{
   title: 'aaaa',
   ids: [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]
}
```

which is equivalent, but much more readable than a binary ObjectOutputStream.

Again, this won't work for all kinds of data.

There is an XML-based bean serialization, too, which also works with almost all data, but I would not call that human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try with JAXB.(Java Architecture for XML Binding)
It can send a JAXB styled object to a xml file.
But you should define a XML Schema file at first.
For more:http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/

Comment: +1 for JAXB, but you do not need an XML schema:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

Answer (score 0):

The human readable that you desire could be `XML` or `JSON`. My answer [How to create object tree from xsd in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292872/how-to-create-object-tree-from-xsd-in-java/9292969#9292969)

might help in giving you pointers to the approach you can follow to achieve what you want.